# How to Create a designation name under parent designation

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How to create below table in oracle apex ? 
There showing (red) parent List of value create when create designation then automatically parent.

[image: Create a designation name under parent designation.]

Comment: Can you please explaining more clearly what you are looking for? I don’t understand.

Comment: pls showing image